# Vaadin and JPA container, store beans or not

Tags: java, database, orm, jpa, vaadin

I'm a first-timer to this and would like to have some guidance regarding how to store objects in a database..

I have an object `Person`, with a couple of fields in it. I have one `PersonContainer` which loads all the objects from the database.

What is best of these two: (or if they both suck, tell me what's the right thing to do)

Store the object just as a `XXX.store(new Person())`

or

Store the object as in `XXX.store(new BeanItem<Person>(new Person()))`?

Whats "good practice" to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to persist [**Business objects**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_object_%28computer_science%29) i.e. objects that represent a business concept of your particular domain, in your case `Person`, etc.

Actually, I suggest to have a look at the [Adding JPA to the Address Book Demo](http://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Adding%20JPA%20to%20the%20Address%20Book%20Demo) page in the Vaadin wiki, you might find some useful information there.

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest to persist Person. The BeanItem class is used by Vaadin for its own purposes (binding etc) so there is no reason to persist those "vaadin purposes" :)

SC